# SQL create multiple vs single "statuses tables"

Tags: sql, database-design

After reviewing many DB designs I'm still not sure what is the best approach.
I am designing a database where most of the entities have different statuses. For example I may have something like

- User statuses: Active, Inactive, Disabled, etc.
- Order statuses: Open, Close, Canceled;
- Office statuses: Open, Close.

And I thinking in two different options.

1) Create one "status" table for every entity

```
    CREATE TABLE UserStatus(
       UserStatusID int,
       Description varchar(255)
    );
    CREATE TABLE OrderStatus(
       OrderStatusID int,
       Description varchar(255)
    );
```

2) Create a single shared status table for all the entities

```
    CREATE TABLE Status(
       StatusID int,
       Description varchar(255)
    );
```

If you could explain which option is better or the advantanges of each one I would be grateful

Comment: The second anti-pattern has a name "one true lookup table" and you shouldn't use it. You can't prevent a user from being assigned an order status with that design

Comment: Interesting, I found this related article https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/one-true-lookup-tables-otlt

Comment: "*it starts to go wrong, and as the system evolves over time, that's just going to get worse*" pretty much sums it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple tables have a key advantage:  You can declare proper foreign key relationships to ensure that the values are correct in the referenced tables.

A single table has a different advantage:  You have all the statuses in one place.  This can be quite handy if you need to do something like translate all the statuses into a different language.

In most cases, I think the first advantage outweighs the second.  In come cases, however, the second can be important.

Comment: The second case can always be simulated by create a view that does a UNION over the individual lookup tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Not really.  The ids won't be unique.

Comment: If that was important I would simply use a single sequence to generate the IDs for all tables.

Answer (score 2):

One more option - create a single shared status table for all the entities with EntityID.
Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Entity(
    EntityID int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_Entity PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Description varchar(255) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Status(
    EntityID int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_Status_Entity 
    FOREIGN KEY(EntityID)   REFERENCES dbo.Entity (EntityID),
    StatusID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Description varchar(255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Status PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    EntityID ASC,
    StatusID ASC)
 CONSTRAINT UQ_Status_EntityID_Name UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (
    EntityID ASC,
    Name ASC)
)
```